# How to save Matplotlib.pyplot.loglog to file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, loglog

I am trying to generate the log-log plot of a vector, and save the generated plot to file.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
... 
plt.loglog(deg_distribution,'b-',marker='o')
plt.savefig('LogLog.png')
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook, in which I get the generated graph as output after statement 2 in the above code, but the saved file is blank.

Comment: Do you call `plt.show()` before `savefig`?

Comment: Tried that too, but the saved image is still blank.

Comment: Have you tried updating `matplotlib`? Maybe try changing the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that pyplot has the concept of the current figure and the current axes. All plotting commands apply to the current axes. So, make sure you plot in the right axes. Here is a WME.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(range(100), 'b-',marker='o')

plt.savefig('test.png')     # apply to the axes `ax`
```